# How do I reference variables from a different file?

Tags: c#, winforms

What I want to do is pass two variables from a button click event to another class in the same file.

Here is my code:

Settings.cs (Windows Form file)

```
namespace ShovelShovel

public partial class Settings : Form
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowSize.SaveData(textBoxWidth.Text, textBoxHeight.Text);
    }
}
}
}
```

SetWindowSize.cs (class file)

```
namespace ShovelShovel

class SetWindowSize
{
    public static void SaveData(string width, string height)
    {          
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("file.dat", FileMode.Create)))
        {
                binaryWriter.Write(width, height);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want `Settings.width` and `Settings.height` in SetWindowSize.cs to get the text from `textBoxWidth` and `textBoxHeight`.

I can't change

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to anything else, since it would break the function of the form, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Define a function setWidth which takes width and height as parameters. Then call it from the click event handler?

Comment: have public static variables for width and height in your settings class? Cann the write method from the That would just solve the issue with the code that you have posted. However, your class names and methods are misleading, the SetWindowSize class and the write method seem to implement some kind of logging or a write to file functionality. Ideally your write should take the string to be written as an input parameter

Comment: @AtoMerZ I'm not sure to do that... I tried, but it says 'ShovelShovel.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'height'. Same for width.

Comment: @ryadavilli They do that. I want to write the window size to a file so the user doesn't have to set it every time the game starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new method to SetWindowSize class and call it from button1_Click

```
public static class SetWindowSize
{
    public static void SaveData(string width, string height)
    {
        File.WriteAllText("file.dat", string.Format("height: {0}, width: {1}.", height, width));
    }
}
```

And button click

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowSize.SaveData(textBoxWidth.Text, textBoxHeight.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, I get the error "No overload for method 'Write' takes 2 arguments." I've updated my original question with my updated code. I've always had this thing where I see only the details, and not the bigger picture, so I tend to make things harder than they should be...

Comment: @Fiona Please "mark as answer" if it works. I think I answered your original question.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I can't vote up, I don't have enough "reputation". Is there a way to do this while still using BinaryWriter?

Comment: @Fiona You dont need to vote up, you have to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to change the signature of the button click event handler, and the other class shouldn't be calling that function anyway.  The button click event handler should be creating an instance of `SetWindowSize` and calling `Write`.  You can add an additional parameter to `Write` to pass the two strings from the button click handler.