# How do I reference a function's variable from another class? - C#

Tags: c#

I am having a hell of a time getting a variable from the function of another class usable in my Game1 (main) class. Specifically, I want to take width and height from the function SaveData in SetWindowSize.cs and use it in ReadSettings in Game1.cs.

I get the error

> 'ShovelShovel.SetWindowSize' does not contain a definition for
>   'height'. Same for 'width'.

Game1.cs (the function only)

```
protected void ReadSettings()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(SetWindowSize.savePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(SetWindowSize.savePath,
                                                          FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
                {
                    SetWindowSize.width = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                    SetWindowSize.height = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

SetWindowSize.cs

```
namespace ShovelShovel
{
            protected void ReadSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(savePath))
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        var windowSize = WindowSizeStorage.ReadSettings();

                        WindowSize.Width = windowSize.Width;
                        WindowSize.Height = windowSize.Height;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much to anyone and everyone that can help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is the exact same concept as your other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795678/how-do-i-reference-variables-from-a-different-file. Of course the error is pretty clear. SetWindowSize does not have height or width variables/properties.

Comment: But I can't create a new function here, as width and height are defined in the creation of the function SaveData.

Comment: Are you getting confused between function parameters and class level variables? I would suggest reading up on scope of these items first.

Comment: CodeCaster has practically written out all your code for you in the answer below.

Comment: Maybe I should just give up. I'm trying my hardest, but I fail at everything i do because of my mental disorder.

Comment: @Fiona The downvoting isn’t a vendetta – probably. It’s simply very hard to remember back to the time you began programming, and show a little humility. Truth be told, I almost wrote a snarky comment here; I remembered just in time how hard it was for me to wrap my head around these difficult concepts. Incidentally, which (if any) book are you using for learning? Languages like C# introduce quite a lot of concepts at once – it makes sense to limit oneself at the beginning to not get confused.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I used the book "A Simple Introduction to Game Programming with Csharp and Xna 3.1". Now I'm working on my own, trying to make a game, very slowly since I admit I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
public class WindowSize
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public static class WindowSizeStorage
{
    public static string savePath = "WindowSize.dat";

    public static WindowSize ReadSettings()
    {   
        var result = new WindowSize();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(SetWindowSize.savePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                result.Width = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                result.Height = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void WriteSettings(WindowSize toSave)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(savePath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(toSave.Width);
            binaryWriter.Write(toSave.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Read
var windowSize = WindowSizeStorage.ReadSettings();

myForm.Width = windowSize.Width;
myForm.Height = windowSize.Height;

// Write
var windowSize = new WindowSize { Width = myForm.Width, Height = myForm.Height };

WindowSizeStorage.WriteSettings(windowSize);
```

Please note that writing an answer like this (presenting all code) is not the common way; I just felt like it. I tried to show some object-oriented design principles, where each class does its own thing.

If you want to transfer compicated objects between methods (i.e. more than one primitive type), you will usually create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) like `WindowSize`.

The `WindowSizeStorage` class has the sole responsibility to store and retreive such a `WindowSize` object. From your code you simply tell the storage to store or retreive the settings you wish.

But as I get from your question and comments, you haven't got much experience using C# or perhaps any programming experience at all. Try to pick up on a tutorial or two so you can understand how to put your thoughts into code.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I am getting an error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryReader.BinaryReader(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments. On the line: using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(new StreamReader(savePath)))

Comment: Thanks again. However, when I try to use your Write method, I get the following errors: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ShovelShovel.WindowSize.Width.get'. I get the same for 'Height'. This is on the line: var windowSize = new...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Function variable outside that function.
To achieve these define static variable assign height and width to the static variable then access it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A function's purpose is not to store and expose variables. You can't access variables if their scope is not wide enough. In your case, you should expose those in a way or another by storing them in the class and making them public, for example :

```
class SetWindowSize
{
    public const string savePath = "file.dat";

    public int width {get; set; }
    public int height {get; set; }

    public static void SaveData(string width, string height)
    {            
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(savePath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(width);
            binaryWriter.Write(height);
            SetWindowSize.width = width;
            SetWindowSize.height = height;
        }
    }
}
}
```

That is far from optimal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your SetWindowSize class does not contain width or height members. You can add them as properties:

```
public class SetWindowSize
{
// other stuff
public int Height {get;set;}
public int Width {get;set;}
// other stuff
}
```

Then you can access them using the SetWindowSize instance:

```
SetWindowSize sws = new SetWindowSize();
sws.Height = 512;
sws.Width = 512;
```